# Postgresql not installing with postgresql cookbook

Tags: chef-infra

I just started using Chef and I'm trying to get Postgresql installed on an EC2 instance. I'm using the `knife-ec2` gem to help with this.

When I run `knife ec2 server create -r "role[postgresql]"` the instance spins up but when I SSH into it to check if Postgresql installed it isn't.

Here is the role for `postgresql.rb`.

```
name 'postgesql'
description 'A single Postgresql server'
run_list(
  'recipe[postgresql]'
)
```

Why is Postgres not being installed?

Comment: Surely chef logs its activities? What do the logs say?

Comment: For those voting to close - this is a valid question for Stackoverflow. Chef is an extension of the Ruby programming language, and this issue is related to Chef, not Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

The default recipe only installs the client. Use the [postgresql::server](https://github.com/hw-cookbooks/postgresql/blob/master/README.md#server) recipe to install the server.

Comment: Even when I tried that nothing happened.

Comment: Can't imagine, why this shouldn't work. Please paste the output of the chef run using postgresql::server.